# Appserv and node.js

Tags: node.js

I have successfully compiled node.js using cygwin on windows.
The problem is that my environment is set up with Appserv.
Is there a way to compile node.js so that it can be used as an executable outside of cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Windows-Port-%28MSVC%29) and [this](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_frm/thread/b20422cd9f53099) - currently there is no native non-cygwin version.